# How to use the "Simple File Upload" feature of Heroku (S3 CDN) in a Angular frontend

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, heroku, file-upload, cdn

How to use the "Simple File Upload" resource of Heroku in an Angular application?

Answer (score 0):

In your Angular application:

1.) In index.html in the head section add:

```
<script src="https://app.simplefileupload.com/buckets/000000yourkey00000000.js"></script>
```

2.) In the template of the component, where you would like to display the upload widget add:

```
<form [formGroup]="imageUploadForm">
   <input
      type="hidden"
      name="image_url"
      id="image_url"
      #image_url
      class="simple-file-upload">
</form>
```

3.) In the component, where you would like to display the upload widget add:

```
@ViewChild('image_url', {static: false}) imageURL: ElementRef;
```

4.) In the component, where you would like to display the upload widget access the URL of the uploaded image like so:

```
const imageURL = this.imageURL.nativeElement.value;
```

Also create a standard FormGroup called imageUploadForm.